# GeckoFx-14 PromptService is not working

Tags: c#, proxy, xulrunner, geckofx

I was testing the GeckoFxTest project which was given with main geckofx source file. But when I was testing the customPrompt for private proxies, unfortunately its not working. I uncommented these lines :

```
GeckoWebBrowser.UseCustomPrompt();

GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = false;
```

and for private proxy I used these codes :

`Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http"] = host; Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = port; Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.ssl"] = host; Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.ssl_port"] = port; Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.type"] = 1;`

Without `GeckoWebBrowser.UseCustomPrompt()` it is prompting for username and password, but after uncommenting it - its keep showing "Access to requested resource disallowed by administrator or you need valid username/password to use this resource". Am I missing anything ?

Thanks

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-14.0/issue/19#submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the issue at the Geckofx's site.
[Here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-14.0/issue/19/promptservice-not-working) is the solution.